# POSTGRESQL: Importing CSV file with an array column

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Is there a way to import a CSV file with an array column to POSTGRESQL with the data below?

```
genres
['documentation']
['crime', 'drama']
['comedy', 'fantasy']
['comedy']
['horror']
['comedy', 'european']
['thriller', 'crime', 'action']
['drama', 'music', 'romance', 'family']
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code or sample data as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: No,  Postgres will not recognize `['crime', 'drama']` as an array: `select '['crime', 'drama']'::varchar[]; ERROR:  syntax error at or near "', '"
...` . To be seen as an array it would need to be: `select '{"crime", "drama"}'::varchar[]; {crime,drama}`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok. Ill just edit the data on excel. Thank you